# Windows 7 or Windows 8 on Retina Macbook

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, resolution, boot-camp, macbook-pro-retina

I'm now ready to finally bootcamp my retina Macbook, due to too many things just not working on Parallels (partly due to memory limit)...

It seems that Windows resolution may be an issue - everything is super tiny in Parallels. Is there a way to have the resolution display be a bit larger? Is windows 7 or windows 8 (via bootcamp) better for a retina macbook in this respect?

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions?

Answer (score 1):

## Windows 8

Right click on desktop, select `Screen Resolution`. Close to bottom of the window, select `Make text and other items larger or smaller`.

Then you can choose 100%, 125% or 150% for text and icons, or even custom sizing options.

Windows 7 should be similar but I don't have Win 7 box now.